# TextInputLayout InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD showing password by default

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, material-components, android-textinputedittext

I created alert dialog with `TextInputLayout` programmatically in fragment. I need to hide password by default, `TextInputLayout` has toggle button and it is working as expected hide/show on click. I tried to keep password hidden by default by settingsingleline to true and other hack i got from other SO answers but i still not able to get desired result. Any idea why i am not getting desired result?

```
TextInputLayout passwordParent = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());
        passwordParent = new TextInputLayout(getActivity());

        TextInputEditText passWord= new TextInputEditText(getActivity());
        passWord.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
        passWord.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        passWord.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

        passwordParent.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE);
        passwordParent.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.show_password_selector);
        passwordParent.addView(passWord);
```

Background XML Selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_remove_red_eye_black_24dp" android:state_checked="true"/> // Visible Eye Icon 
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_visibility_off_black_24dp"/> // Hide Eye Icon
</selector>
```

[image]

**Edit:** It's working by adding  `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` into input type like this `passWord.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` but the icon still stay the same, its still showing wrong eye icon.

Comment: did you try to set password transformation as transformation method?

Comment: @PeerNet i tried but still will can try again

Answer (score 0):

Try moving addView(passWord) up by two lines, like this :

```
passwordParent.addView(passWord);
passwordParent.setEndIconMode(TextInputLayout.END_ICON_PASSWORD_TOGGLE);
passwordParent.setEndIconDrawable(R.drawable.show_password_selector);
```